# Copy files from one folder to another

Tags: backup, restore, copy

Rather new at Ubuntu so help would be greatly appreciated.

I need time copy basically this media/directoryA/directoryB/any file based on a certain .ext

Then I need to copy that back to music/directory and structure above.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to copy all .ext files from media/directoryA/directoryB to music/directory?

If yes, try the following command:

```
cp media/directoryA/directoryB/*.ext  music/directory/
```

If the media directory and the music directory are not in the same path, it is recommended to use absolute paths for both paths of the command.

Answer (score 0):

#Important: Get the exact and proper file locations.

Suppose I want to copy all the .ext files to a specific directory.

- The directory of the file to be copied is:/media/user/Archive/2023/
- Directory of the folder where the file will be copied: /home/user/Music/collection

---

Command to be given is:
sudo cp -v fromDIR/*.filetype toDIR

- **`sudo cp -v /media/user/Archive/2023/*.ext /home/user/Music/collection/`**

---